# Time ticking bomb scenario

Tags: politics-government

Suppose that a person with knowledge of an imminent terrorist attack, that will kill many people, is in the hands of the authorities and that he will disclose the information needed to prevent the attack only if he is tortured. What would the Torah think? Should he be tortured?

For more n=information about this scenario, here is the Wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticking_time_bomb_scenario